# Can somebody give me an example for the zip() function in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

In Python's [document](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip), it says the following things for the zip function:

"The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed. This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups using zip(*[iter(s)]*n)."

I have a difficulty in understanding the zip(*[iter(s)]*n) idiom. Can any body give me an example on when we should use that idiom?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020, but let me leave this here for reference.

The `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` idiom is used to split a flat list into chunks.

For example:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'first', 'second', 'third']
>>> list(zip(*[iter(mylist)]*3))
[(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('first', 'second', 'third')]
```

The idiom is analyzed [here](https://www.stavros.io/posts/brilliant-or-insane-code/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what documentation you're using, but [this version of zip() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), has this example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> x2, y2 = zip(*zipped)
>>> x == list(x2) and y == list(y2)
True
```

It interpolates two lists together, in respective order, and it also has an "unzip" feature

And since you asked, here's a slightly more understandable example:

```
>>> friends = ["Amy", "Bob", "Cathy"]
>>> orders = ["Burger", "Pizza", "Hot dog"]
>>> friend_order_pairs = zip(x, y)
>>> friend_order_pairs
[("Amy", "Burger"), ("Bob", "Pizza"), ("Cathy", "Hot dog")]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In your second example, should we change zip(x,y) to zip(friends, orders)?   And the document I am reading is from    https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip    Thanks again！

Answer (score 0):

zip() is for sticking two or more lists together.

```
names=['bob','tim','larry']

ages=[15,36,50]

zip(names,ages)

Out: [('bob', 15), ('tim', 36), ('larry', 50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use izip instead. 
When working with very large data sets, you can use izip which uses a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and only evaluates results when requested - therefore great for memory management and much better performance. I usually use generator based variants of python modules when possible.

imagine an example like this:

```
from itertools import islice,izip

w = xrange(9000000000000000000)
x = xrange(2000000000000000000)
y = xrange(9000000000000000000)
z = xrange(9000000000000000000)

# The following only returns a generator that holds an iterator for the first 100 items 
# without loading that large mess of numbers into memory
first_100_items_generator = islice(izip(w,x,y,z), 100) 

# Iterate through the generator and return only what you need - first 100 items
first_100_items = list(first_100_items_generator) 

print(first_100_items)

Output:
[ (0, 0, 0, 0),
  (1, 1, 1, 1),
  (2, 2, 2, 2),
  (3, 3, 3, 3),
  (4, 4, 4, 4),
  (5, 5, 5, 5),
  (6, 6, 6, 6),
  (7, 7, 7, 7),
  (8, 8, 8, 8),
  (9, 9, 9, 9),
  (10, 10, 10, 10),
  (11, 11, 11, 11)
  ...
  ...
  ]
```

So here I have four large arrays of numbers, I used izip to zip the values then used islice to pick out the first 100 items.

The nice thing about using xrange, izip and islice is that are use generators, therefore they are not executed until the final "list()" method is called on it.

It's a bit of a digression into generators but good to know when you start doing large data processing in python.

Info on generators:

[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07-K4LFhBMc)

[Generator intro](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Answer (score 0):

I use it to create dictionaries when I have a separate lists of keys and values:

```
>>> keys = ('pi', 'c', 'e')
>>> values = (3.14, 3*10**8, 1.6*10**-19)
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'c': 300000000, 'pi': 3.14, 'e': 1.6000000000000002e-19}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to iterate over two lists and their indices using `enumerate()` together with `zip()`:

```
alist = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
blist = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print i, a, b
```

`zip()` basically combines two or more items to form another list of equal length:

```
>>> alist = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> blist = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
>>> 
>>> zip(alist, blist)
[('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3')]
>>>
```